# Rspec / CapyBara how to expect record not to be saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am testing a scenario with CapyBara where I expect the record NOT to be valid.

```
Given "the customer is not an athlete" do
  @customer = create(:athlete, :shop=> @shop, :first_name=>"Birglend", :last_name=>"Firglingham", :email=>"birglendfirglingham@gmail.com")
end

Then "I should not see that the customer is an athlete" do
  expect(page).not_to have_css('.athlete-row')
end
```

But before it can get to the "Then", I get an "ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved" exception. This is caused by a before_save callback that I have to check if the customer is an athlete. If they're not an athlete, the method returns false and I do *not* want the record to be saved.e.g.

```
before_save :check_athlete_status

def check_athlete_status
 #return false unless self is an athlete
end
```

But I have a feeling this is not the correct way because this is an expected scenario and should not be throwing exceptions. How do I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should just use validations rather than a before_save.  You generally want to avoid before and after create/save callbacks unless you really need them.  That said you can expect the call to raise an exception if that is the desired behavior.

Comment: That was actually exactly what I was looking for. I switched it to a custom validation validate :athlete?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to mix what a model test and a feature test do here.

There are a couple ways to test this.

I am going to drop the `Given`/`Then` syntax because I don't have any experience using that gem.

1) A model spec:

```
RSpec.describe Athlete, type: :model do
  context 'with invalid status' do
    let(:athlete) { FactoryGirl.build(:athlete, :shop=> @shop, :first_name=>"Birglend", :last_name=>"Firglingham", :email=>"birglendfirglingham@gmail.com") }

    it "raises an exception" do
      expect { athlete.save }.to raise_exception(ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved)
    end
  end
end
```

2) You can also change the feature test to do whatever your `Given` is doing via the interface:

```
feature 'Admin creates athlete' do
  given(:athlete) { FactoryGirl.build(:athlete, :shop=> @shop, :first_name=>"Birglend", :last_name=>"Firglingham", :email=>"birglendfirglingham@gmail.com") }

  scenario 'with invalid status' do
    # We're testing that your custom callback stops saving the record.
    visit '/athletes/new'
    select @shop.title, from: 'Shop'
    fill_in 'First name', with: 'Birglend'
    fill_in 'Last name', with: 'Firglingham'
    fill_in 'Email', with: 'birglendfirglingham@gmail.com'
    select 'Not an athlete' from: 'Status'
    click_button 'Create Athlete'
    expect(page).to have_content 'There was an error creating the athlete'

    # I'd argue that these next lines, what you're trying to test, really shouldn't be tested here. What you should be testing is that the form provides feedback that the athlete record wasn't created.
    click_link 'Athletes'
    expect(page).not_to have_css('.athlete-row')
  end
end
```

I don't know what your interface is supposed to be doing, so I just made something up above. Hope that helps you go down the right path.